# what would cause a field to return array in php?

Tags: php

I'm working on modifying an existing shopping cart application so I'm fumbling through this. Using PHP 5 and mySql.

The code sends an email message to the client and to the user that shows which product they are interested in. The page is rendering the product and the attributes correctly. When the email is sent the product portion works but the attributes don't work.

It should show the attributes, but it just has the word "Array."

*The email portion sends this:*

Product Name: (whatever the product is)

Attributes: Array

Products Options Name: (whatever product option is)

*This code is used to generate the product info in the email:*

```
$message .= '<p style="font:bold 14px/25px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0; padding:0;"><strong>List of Products</strong></p><br /><br />' . "\n";
if (is_array($arr_product_list)){
        foreach($arr_product_list as $value) {
            $message .= '<strong>' . $value . '</strong><br />' . "\n";
        }
}
```

*This is the code used to display the products on the rendered page:*

```
$productsname = $product['productsName'];
$attributes = $product['attributes'];
$products_options_name = $value['products_options_name'];

$arr_product_list[] = "<strong>Product Name:</strong> $productsname <br />";
$arr_product_list[] .= "<strong>Attributes:</strong> $attributes <br />";
$arr_product_list[] .= "<strong>Products Options Name:</strong> $products_options_name 
<br />";
$arr_product_list[] .=
"---------------------------------------------------------------";
```

*And here's what is showing on the rendered page where they should choose the product and attribute:*

```
<div class="wrapperAttribsOptions">
  <h4 class="optionName back"><label class="attribsSelect" for="attrib-14">SPK
  Model</label></h4>
<div class="back">
  <select name="id[14]" id="attrib-14">
   <option value="43">SPK-4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I guess where I'm really confused is I don't see where anything is called attrib-14 or id14 in the code that sends the email so I'm having problems figuring this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By using `xyz[]` in the form name, you are turning the resulting `xyz` variable in PHP into an array. It takes all the `xyz` values from the form and creates an array of them.

You would have to resolve the array in php, e.g. using

```
 foreach($attributes as $field)
  $arr_product_list[] = "$field<br />";
```

or use a different notation for your fields:

```
<select name="id_14" id="attrib-14">
```

however, that way you have to deal with however many `id_*` fields there are in your POST input.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change everything, just get the email notification to work. It's displaying everything fine.

Comment: What I mean to say is, the page is rendered through generated code and I'm not even sure how it is generated. There is already a foreach in the first block of code. Is there a way to modify that and get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that products store their attributes as an array, which makes sense since there can be many.

Try changing this line:

```
$arr_product_list[] .= "<strong>Attributes:</strong> $attributes <br />";
```

to

```
$arr_product_list[] .= "<strong>Attributes:</strong>".join(', ', $attributes)."<br />";
```

Comment: That's the line that is displaying the products on the page and it's working fine. Products and attributes are displayed correctly. The problem getting that information into the email once it's selected. I think the problem is in that first block of code.

Comment: I tried it and now the Attributes is empty. Before it had the word Array in the email, now nothing. The page does still render correctly but it didn't help with the email.